# What is better between Activity and AppCompactActivity to use Toolbar?

Tags: android, material-design

When I created a new activity, it extends ActionBarActivity but it's deprecated.

At that moment, I have two options:

1) Used `Activity` and `android:Theme.Material` in my style like that :

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material">
```

**Or**

2) Used `AppCompatActivity` and `Theme.AppCompat` :

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
```

**So my question is, what is better between Activity and AppCompactActivity to use Android Material Design and Toolbar ?**

Comment: Use AppCompatActivity if you want to support pre v21 devices;

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It isn't a matter of which is "better". Which one you should use depends on what versions of Android you are supporting.

`Theme.Material` is only available on devices running API 21 (Lollipop) and up. If you wish to use the Material theme on devices running API 20 and below, you need to use AppCompat.

> When I created a new activity, it extends ActionBarActivity but it's deprecated.

This is a very recent change. As of version 22.1 of AppCompat, `ActionBarActivity` has been deprecated in favor of [`AppCompatActivity`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/AppCompatActivity.html).

Comment: ActionBarActivity wasn't *renamed*. It was deprecated to favor AppCompatActivity.